# Passing url id from react-router to mongoose

Tags: express, mongoose, react-router, mern

i'm trying to learn the MERN stack and this is a simple silly problem that i haven't been able to figure it out for a couple of days.
i am trying to make a GET request to the api using express and mongoose for the backend and react, react router for the front end.
This is the api request:

```
router.get('/:id', (req, res) => {
    Product.findById(req.params.id)
        .then(product => res.json(product))
});
```

I set the route to this:

```
<Route path="/:id" component={Product}></Route>
```

And this is the Product component from which i perform the GET request with axios:

```
componentWillMount() {
        axios.get("/api/products/:id")
            .then(res => this.setState({
                product: res.data
            }))
            .catch(err => console.log(err))
    }
```

And it gave the error of:

```
CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value ":id" at path "_id" for model "product"
```

I've been looking up for days and still haven't find a way to fix this, i think it have something to do with mongoose scheema's automatic id is `_id` which is causing some problems for the api.

Schema:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema; // Create Schema 
const ProductSchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  pic: {
    type: String,
  },
  price: {
    type: Number,
  },
  sale: {
    type: Number,
  }
});
module.exports = Product = mongoose.model('product', ProductSchema);
```

Thanks in advance guys!

Comment: Can you post the schema/model for Product?

Comment: `const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

// Create Schema
const ProductSchema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    pic: {
        type: String,
    },
    price: {
        type: Number,
    },
    sale: {
        type: Number,
    }
});

module.exports = Product = mongoose.model('product', ProductSchema);
`

Comment: the id is automaticly generated by mongoose

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this after couple of hours google, it turns out when i click the link, it's directed to `products/:id` not the actual id, all i had to do is `const link = '/products/' + this.props.product._id` and pass the `link` in the `<a>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the validity of your `req.params.id` as a valid id for mongo to query with. Error is specific about the id not being an actual objectId mongo can use.

Comment: i have check with mongoose.Types.ObjectId.isValid() and it returns `false` how can i convert the req.params.id to an ObjectId?

Comment: use  `mongoose.Types.ObjectId(<your string>)`. false wont cut it however. It needs to be a mongo _id in string format

Comment: also, i have tested the api with postman and it worked flawlessly, but not here